# How can I provide stdin to ed, which need a filename?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ed

Need some unix shell basic here:

For command that I see no "-" target in , say ed:

```
print '%-2p\nq' | ed -s FILE
```

Can I provide a stream from stdout of some cmd, rather than FILE name, as the data to be processed:

```
SomeCMD | ed -s SOMETHING_MAGICAL <<< 'print '%-2p\nq'
```

Is is possible?

Comment: [Can I ask what you're *really* trying to achieve?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)  Editing a stream seems like something a [Stream EDitor](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed) might do.

Comment: i.e.: `SomeCmd | sed '2p;3q'` or `SomeCmd | sed '1d;4q'`, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ed** reads its commands from stdin, so if your file is also on stdin, how do you work?

In fact, you *can* feed file input over stdin, if you concatenate its output with a single line

```
i
```

at the beginning, to start writing in the data, then append a single *.* to end the input, followed by any commands.  You can even output the results to stdout. Do remember that it will break if there is a line in the file with nothing but a single *.* in it.

So if a file **input.file** contains this:

```
First line
Second line
Third line
```

And a file **commands.list** contains this:

```
.
1d
1,$w /dev/stdout
```

Then this command line...

```
echo i | cat - input.file commands.list | ed -s
```

Will output this:

```
Second line
Third line
```

Dare I say **tadaaaaa!** ?

Note: you can probably protect against the case of single **.** lines in the file by piping the file through a filter that escapes any such lines and then unescaping them again with **ed** commands.  I leave that to your ingenuity.

Another note:  you really should use **sed** for this, but I couldn't let the *it can't be done* comments go by.

Comment: Amazing! Your 'tadaaa!' was justified!

Answer (score 3):

You use `r` to read a command output into the text buffer. So, portable:

```
printf '%s\n' 'r !df -h' g/tmpfs/d ,p q | ed -s
```

or

```
ed -s << IN
r !df -h
g/tmpfs/d
,p
q
IN
```

The above reads in the output of `df -h`, deletes the lines matching `tmpfs` and prints the result.
If your shell supports process substitution:

```
printf '%s\n' g/tmpfs/d ,p q | ed -s <(df -h)
```

With `gnu ed` that `SOMETHING_MAGICAL` is called `!`.
As per the `man` page:

> Start edit by reading in 'file' if given.  If 'file' begins with a
>   '!', read output of shell command.

```
printf '%s\n' g/tmpfs/d ,p q | ed -s '!df -h'
```

or, with *herestring*:

```
ed -s '!df -h' <<< $'g/tmpfs/d\n,p\nq\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Effectively, instead of 'piping' into ed, you can use 'process substitution' to pass the output of your command as the input to be edited, leaving the standard pipe free to take pre-scripted ed commands.

Example:

```
echo '#
,s/\/dev\/\(\w*\) .* \b\(.*\)%.*$/DEVICE \1 is \2% full!/
,p
Q' | ed -s <(df 2> /dev/null | tail -n +2 | egrep "^/dev/")

DEVICE sda6 is 90% full!
DEVICE sda2 is 88% full!
```

Explanation:

Process substitution (the `<()` part) turns the output of `df 2> /dev/null | tail -n +2 | egrep "^/dev/"` into the contents of a temporary file descriptor, which is then used as an input file to `ed -s`.

At the same time, ed commands are passed via echo into a pipe.

Echo here is used in multiline single-quote mode without interpretation of escape sequences; if you're not too bothered about not having everything appear on a single line, then this is the most straightforward way to pass ed commands without having to go into escape-sequences hell.

Specifically, we are passing four ed commands:

- A comment (just to align the remaining commands on the console)
- A substitution command
- A 'print all' command
- A 'quit unconditionally' command, to prevent any warning messages that could have been printed on the terminal.